# create a batch script on windows that periodically starts a sql function

Tags: postgresql

I need to create a batch script on windows that periodically starts a sql function written in 'plpgsql'.

I can use windows schedule task for creating a cron job but I don't know how to write the script.

Comment: *‘but I don't know how to write the script’* – batch file script or SQL script?

Comment: batch file script.

Comment: You may not need any batch file at all. In your Scheduler Task, you can just specify the command line tool you are going to invoke to run your script, with all the parameters necessary. There's no need to write a batch file for a single command like that.

Answer (score 4):

Use [psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-psql.html) with a command to execute the function, eg:

```
postgres=> create function f() returns void language plpgsql as $$begin null; end;$$;
CREATE FUNCTION
postgres=> \q
```

```
root@maidenhead:~# psql --command="select f()" postgres postgres
 f
---

(1 row)
```

...which is easily set up to run via Task Scheduler, no batch file required (thanks @Craig)

Comment: ... which is easily set up to run via Task Scheduler, no batch file required.